# React app is looking for static files in different location when using proxy

Tags: reactjs, apache, deployment

I have used `npx create-react-app my-app` to create a react app.

The I used `npm run build` to build the app and deployed it using `serve -s build`

I'm using a proxy server to make my app publicly available.

My httpd configs looks like below,

```
/react_app http://192.168.1.100:3000
```

Whats really happening is once a request comes to `http://<my public domain>/react_app` I need to show my react app.

but the problem is it looks for the static files in `http://<my public domain>/static/..` instead of `http://<my public domain>/react_app/static/....`

In my `index.html`I have set all absolute paths to relative paths as below,

```
ex:
<script src="./static/js/******.chunk.js"></script>
<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json"/>
```

But it didn't fix my issue. Are there any way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Building for relative paths for `create-react-app`

There can be two places where you could define relative path

1) By default, Create React App produces a build assuming your app is hosted at the server root.
To override this, specify the homepage in your package.json, for example:

```
  "homepage": "http://mywebsite.com/react_app",
```

This will let Create React App correctly infer the root path to use in the generated HTML file.

2) If you are using react-router@^4, relative path can be set using `basename`

```
<Router history={browserHistory} basename={'react_app'}>
  <Route path="/" component={App} />
</Router>
```

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to add base tag(URL):

```
<html>
<head>
   <base href="./react_app" target="_blank" />
</head>
...
</html>
```

Some useful references on this - https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths and the PUBLIC_URL https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration.

Answer (score 1):

where did you store assets? If it is not the `public` folder, I think you should take a look at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder